# How do i count number of words?

Tags: c++

how do i make this code run for word tally which counts words. Whenever i put a bunch of .... or !!!! it gives me 13+ word count which is incorrect.

when i tab or "...." it ends up giving me large numbers, or doesn't include them. Words also include groups of (  ,   ;   :   !   ?).

```
string word;
int voweltally(0), contally(0), uppertally(0), lowertally(0), punctally(0), wordtally(1);
int d;

cout << "Enter some text. Letters and the following punctuation only please . , : ; ! ?" << endl;
cout << "Pressing enter/return will end the text." << endl;
getline (cin, word);

d=word.length();


for (int i=0; i<d; i++) {
    if (((toupper(word[i])=='A')||(toupper(word[i])=='E')||(toupper(word[i])=='I')||(toupper(word[i])=='O')||(toupper(word[i])=='U'))) {
        voweltally++;
    }
    else {
        if (((word[i]!='.')&&(word[i]!=',')&&(word[i]!=':')&&(word[i]!=';')&&(word[i]!='!')&&(word[i]!='?'))&&(word[i]!=' ')&&(word[i]!='\t'))
        contally++;
    }
}


for (int i=0; i<d; i++) {

    if (isupper(word[i])){
        uppertally++;
   }
    else if (islower(word[i])) {
        lowertally++;
    }      
}

for (int i=0; i<d; i++) {

    if ((word[i]=='.')||(word[i]==',')||(word[i]==':')||(word[i]==';')||(word[i]=='!')||(word[i]=='?')) { // good
        punctally++;
    }
```

Everything works well till this part for counting words, here are my two initial ideas for counting the number of words

```
    //if (((word[i]!=' ')||(word[i]!='\t'))&&((word[i+1]==' ')||(word[i+1]=='\t'))) { //check work on this
}
for (int i=0; i<d; i++) {
    if (((word[i]!=' ')||(word[i]!='\t'))&&(word[i+1]==' ')){
    wordtally++;
    }
}


cout << "The number of vowels is: " << voweltally << endl;
cout << "The number of consonants is: " << contally << endl;
cout << "The number of uppercase letters is: " << uppertally << endl;
cout << "The number of lowercase letters is: " << lowertally << endl;
cout << "The number of punctuation characters is: " << punctally << endl;
cout << "The number of words is: " << wordtally << endl;
cout << "Exiting program ..." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a big set of comparisons in the first *else if* using interval comparison between 'B' and 'Z' is better.

Comment: `strchr` function must be used instead of many comparisons in other if-conditions. If you rework you code it will function properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe word counting will work if it is implemented like below.

```
for (int i = 1; i < d; i++) {
  if (isalpha(word[i - 1]) && !isalpha(word[i])) {
    wordtally++;
  }
}
if (d > 0 && isalpha(word[d - 1])) {
    wordtally++;
}
```